# Is there a way to verify a user name exists in SVN?

Tags: svn, user-accounts

I'm hoping there's some non-admin command a credentialed user with a given SVN server can query into the server to ask "does user xxxx exist". There's an admin we've been waiting on to create users and they're pretty unresponsive and are starting to block our team. The new users aren't too familiar with SVN or source control so I'd like to quickly verify on their behalf that they even have accounts.

Comment: SVN does not have an user account management system. It uses external authentication systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN is version control. User access is performed by wrapper. It could be Apache, subversion server etc. but not SVN itself.
We're talking about two different layers of OSI. SVN is application layer, user access is session layer.

Comment: Aha, I may but under some false assumptions. So let's say as a concrete example we're using Active Directory for authentication which for any large company would have a ton of users who are not developers. What would the SVN admin need to do to single out specific users from the global set to give access to SVN stuff?

Comment: You'd rather ask the same question on serverfault. Basically, your admin needs to create a group or SVN users in AD and add them into group, and grant access to the group. Or install Apache LDAP-auth ext and set up for virtual directory. Btw, it's out of software engineering scope, it's system integration question.

Comment: authorization != authentication. And this is not about a wrapper at all.